# Плагин для android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, плагин

У меня есть много проектов для android созданных при помощи android studio. Но что мне не очень удобно так это то, что мне нужно постоянно делать построение всего проекта для показа приложения на эмуляторе, так вот в веб-дизайне есть много плагинов которые показывают все изменения на страничке в режиме live, то есть вы можете увидеть все изменения вашей странички без перезагрузки ее в браузере. Может кто-то знает есть подобные плагины для android studio? Или постоянное построение проекта неизбежно в для такого вида разработки.

Comment: Если есть изменения в коде, то новый код нужно компилировать. Иначе никак.

Comment: Боюсь вы плохо понимаете или не знаете понятий : **интерпретируемый** или **компилируемый** язык. Java - компилируемый язык и то, о чем вы спрашиваете в принципе не возможно для этого языка.

Comment: @Nuclominus, насчет "в принципе" вы поторопились. Есть понятие HotSwap для JVM, но для Андроид так и нет нормально работающих решений.